# R Ifelse returning a large list of variables rather than single

Tags: r

I've replicated it in a fairly simple example:

```
alt<-c(1:25)
x<-rnorm(25,1)
x[x<0]<-0
df<-data.frame(alt,x)
df['z']<-ifelse(df['alt']%%2==0,df['x'],0)
```

I get
`Warning message: In ... provided 25 variables to replace 1 variables`.

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong please? Much appreciated.

Comment: Try `ifelse(df[,'alt']%%2==0, df[,'x'],0)`. `df['alt']` and `df['x']` are still `data.frame` with one column.  You can convert to `vector` and then use `ifelse`.

Comment: or use `ifelse(df$alt%%2==0,...)`

Comment: In addition, whenever we get a strange output, it is better to check the structure `str(df['x'])`.  It will give some idea about why it didn't work.  Also, if we use `[[`, it will return a `vector`.  Please check `?Extract` to get more info.

Comment: Thanks. df$val works fine. Plugging a gap in my understanding of dataframes :)